# Global getter javascript

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, getter

In javascript, you can set object property getters like so

```js
const obj = {
  get a() {
    return 1
  }
}

console.log(obj.a) // 1
```

Is it possible to define a *global* getter? Something like:

```js
let a = get() { return 1 }
console.log(a) // 1
```

Or, in the node REPL, obj shows up as: `{a: [Getter]}`, so is there some sort of constructor I could use: `let a = new Getter(() => {return 1})`

Also, can I do the same with setters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since *global* variables are attached to the `window` object, you can do so using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  get: function() {
    console.log('you accessed "window.a"');
    return this._a
  },
  set: function(val) {
    this._a = val;
  }
});

a = 10;

console.log(a);
```

Note that in Node.js, [the global object is called `global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global), not `window`.

[image: Node.js]

Comment: Is this possible in node.js?

Comment: Yes, just replace `window` with `global`. https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: This worked for me in Node.js after I changed the form from `get value() {` to `get () {` and `set value(val) {` to `set (val) {`. For some reason, naming the getter and setter interfered somehow. Note that you can't have `writable: true,` and `set value(val) {` simultaneously or you get `TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute, #<Object>`